# Output text before <img> tag

Tags: javascript, image, onload

This my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById('youtubeimg').src;
      document.write(youtubeimgsrc); 
</script>

  <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-xf7anhq4eRo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wQIFalodFjE/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg" id="youtubeimg">
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vrnsydLb/

I have to put script code before img but it is not working. I tried onload, it worked but all content was removed in page. Is there any way for work?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: I have mybb forum. I want to get first image src in first post. I wanna use this image as cover photo of thread. (like thumbnail)

Comment: Please don't use `document.write`, it's a very expensive call that triggers a document reparse. Consider using `document.createElement` with `appendChild` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function toRun() {

        var src = document.getElementById('bar').getAttribute('src');
        document.getElementById('foo').textContent = src;
    }

    window.onload = toRun;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-xf7anhq4eRo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wQIFalodFjE/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg" id="bar">
    <div id="foo"></div> ##must be closed##
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oopps. It was be like this: <div id="mesaj1"><img src="photo.jpg"></div> I want to get img src in div

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function toRun() {

            var src = document.getElementById('bar').getAttribute('src'),
                text = document.createTextNode(src),
                container = document.getElementById("mesaj1");

            container.insertBefore(text, container.childNodes[0]);
        }

        window.onload = toRun;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mesaj1"><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-xf7anhq4eRo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wQIFalodFjE/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg" id="bar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would also suggest possible hiding the "mesaj1" div using css, and then showing it at the end of the toRun() function, to prevent the image from showing up without the text right before onload is called.

Comment: I don't wanna use id on images.

Comment: You can use **container.childNodes[1]** to get the first image, regardless of id. Try this one: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rLs4safy/4/)

Comment: When i use this in html-body it is not working http://jsfiddle.net/rLs4safy/5/  and i want to put where i want place.